# How to spawn worker with PM2

Tags: node.js, worker, pm2

By using PM2 I've lost the ability to run native clustering that I used to spawn workers, such as in:

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  cluster.schedulingPolicy = cluster.SCHED_NONE;
  for (var i = 1; i < CPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
  Object.keys(cluster.workers).forEach(function(id) {
    cluster.workers[id].on('message', logpi);
  });
  cluster.on('death', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.error('Death:', worker.pid);
    cluster.fork();
  });
  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.error('Exit:', worker.pid);
    cluster.fork();
  });
  require('./worker.js');
} else {
  require('./server.js');
}
```

How would I go about to spawn workers while launching PM2 in cluster mode `$ pm2 start app.js -i 0` ?

Comment: What is the purpose - one master process and communication between all others?

Comment: long running worker, clean-up and backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When use pm2's cluster mode, pm2 implementation master part for you, there is no way to inject worker.js into master(pm2).

Your app.js is no use, you can start your app use server.js directly, like this:

```
pm2 start server.js -i 0
```

You can inject worker.js to server.js, such as try to lock a file(https://github.com/baudehlo/node-fs-ext), if locked, then run worker.js.

Comment: would there be a benefit of running a separate worker application in forked mode as opposed to doing it within the clustered app itself? wouldn't running in the clustered app defeat the purpose? i don't know, that's why i'm asking.. benefits of spawning processes from a forked versus clustered pm2 process

Comment: If worker.js close coupling with server.js, such as require the database connections established by server.js or any in memory information in server.js, then let one of the server.js instance to run worker.js(not fork).

Otherwise start worker.js standalone with another pm2 app(one instance) or startup worker.js in crontab.

Comment: Thanks @tangxinfa! one last question to pick your brain before accepting your answer .. is there a benefit to spawn a childProcess inside a standalone single instance pm2 app ?

Comment: Why you need spawn a new childProcess by yourself? Please let the standalone single instance pm2 app execute your child process's code directly, pm2 is a process manager for all your apps(also include your worker.js), with pm2 your childProcess(worker.js) is visible and manageable with pm2 tools.